# Issue finding the process id from shell scipt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

mySample.sh

```
pid=$(ps -Af | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk ' { print $2 } ');  
echo $pid
```

The above command is printing and killing the temporary process that  was created for grep
Even though i do not have any process running with Abcd, 
This is printing pid
Any ways to ignore it,
iam actually ignoring it using `grep -v`, still...

```
./mySample.sh Abcd
 6251 6378 6379
```

Any Issue in fetching the process id.?

Basic command line output is below,After running a process with name Acc_Application_One

> [root@localhost Desktop]# ps -Af | grep Acc
>
> root      6251  2758  0 16:16 pts/1    00:00:00 ./Acc_Application_One
>
> root      7288  2758  0 16:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep Acc

Changed  mySample.sh

```
    pgrep -fl "$1"
```

And the output is

> [root@localhost Desktop]# mySample.sh Acc_Application_One
>
> 6251 7289

Comment: You also need to ignore the `mySample` process with `grep -v`.

Comment: most `ps`s have a `tree` option. Do some debugging outside of your script and see what the process `tree` for your `./mySample.sh` looks like. If you're lucky  your system my have `pstree $PID` available. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kill a process with the pattern anywhere in command line use `pkill -f`:

```
pkill -f "$1"
```

As per `man pkill`:

> `-f` Match the pattern **anywhere** in the full argument string of the process instead of just the executable name.

Similarly you can use `pgrep -f "$1"` to list the process id of the matching process.

Comment: He's not trying to kill the process in his script. And he just wants to match the command name, not match it anywhere in the line.

Comment: I would still suggest using `pgrep -f` rather than piped `ps`, `grep`, `awk` etc

Comment: It does'nt show anything if i remove -f flag, though my process is running

Comment: @anubhava : pgrep -f is working , but is same, Even that is printing an extra process id.

Comment: ok what does `pgrep -fl "$1"` show to you? May be there is some other matching process

Comment: @anubhava :  i have one process running

[root@localhost Desktop]# ps -Af | grep Acc
   
root      6251  2758  0 16:16 pts/1    00:00:00 ./Acc_Application_One
root      7288  2758  0 16:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep Acc

[root@localhost Desktop]# mySample.sh Acc_Application_One
6251 7289

This command is outputting 2 pid's

Comment: Can you show output of `pgrep -fl "$1"` by editing the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97061/discussion-between-user2256825-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Try something much simpler:

```
pid=$(pgrep "$1")
```

And if you want to kill it:

```
pkill "$1"
```

Comment: Both of them are nt  working, Infact, they are not fetching the process id's.
Somehow, the original command i have posted is fetching exta pid's .
ps: Iam using Redhat 6.2(its pretty old)

Comment: You may need `pgrep -f` as shown in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will become clear when you remove the awk: mySample.sh will have Abcd as well.

```
ps -Af | grep " $1" | grep -Ev "grep|$0" | awk ' { print $2 } '
```

Comment: ./mySamele.sh Acc_Application_One
6251 7303 7304 7306
This is giving  4 proc id's , even though i have one process running

Answer (score 0):

Changed mySample.sh script with below code
And This is just fetching the processId  using the parameter sent
and killing it

```
pid=$(pgrep -fl $1 | grep -v '[k]ill_script'| awk ' { print $1 } ')
echo $pid
if [[ -n ${pid} ]]; then
echo "Stopping Acc Application $1  with pid=${pid}"
kill -9 ${pid}
fi
```

Thanks